# Mac connected to iPhone but no internet

Tags: iphone, network

My mac is connected to my iPhone through USB but I cannot access to internet. I've Googled on this subject but all I can find is very basic advice like "reset your connection" or "Have you tried to turn id off and on again".

How do I diagnose the connection ?

I'm looking for tools both on mac and iPhone that are able to show what's going when mac is trying to connect. It can be terminal commands. I can install terminal on iPhone if necesseray.

Comment: Have you enabled Personal Hotspot on the phone? Have you checked the Mac's Network connection is green & an IP address is assigned? Have you asked your phone's service provider if tethering is supported on your plan?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling the app 1Blocker on iPhone solve the problem. I've ask 1Blocker team if they're aware of the issue.